# Закон об образовании - как правильно?

Tags: орфография

"Депутаты приняли проект Закона "Об образовании" - будущего своеобразного кодекса России".

В данном случае это неофициальное название закона. Как правильно (с какой буквы - заглавной или строчной, с кавычками или без них)?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще-то в неофициальных названиях заглавные буквы употребляться не должны, да и кавычки как-то не смотрятся... Я бы написал  "... проект закона об образовании..."
В официальных названиях писать "закон" с заглавной тоже, имхо, не стоит (кроме некоторых специальных случаев), но там приходится считаться с тем, что заглавная вопреки правилам прописана в самом официальном названии.
Как вариант могу предложить только написание <<... проект "Закона об образовании"...>>. 
Это на случай, если неофициальное название общепринято и уникально. В данном случае, пожалуй, это так и есть.

Answer (score 1):

Конспект книги "Об образовании". Проект закона "Об образовании". Законов много, один из них - "Об образовании" (название закона по типу - название книги). Государственные законы почему-то принято писать с заглавной буквы, а, например, относящиеся к морали и проч., - с прописной. Поэтому мне кажется, что в вопросе корреспондент написал неправильно слово "закон" - с заглавной буквы, потому что это ещё только - проект, а не принятый Закон. В остальном корреспондент (а заодно и главный редактор) - вполне-вполне ответственные товарищи-господа. Мне так думается, но, как говорится, торг не только возможен, но даже поощряется.

Comment: >Государственные законы почему-то принято  
  
Кем принято? депутатами? так у них мания величия.

Comment: Ну,зачем Вы так уж уничижительно о них? Там ведь тоже люди есть: и грамотные, и культурные, и рассудительные, и прочая, и прочая, и прочая. Конечно, (государственные) законы - с прописной буквы, а принятый Закон "О государстве" стоит того,чтобы написать его с заглавной буквы, Но даже если принят Закон "О проституции" - его тоже с заглавной буквы следует писать. Однако если Вы против того, чтобы Этот закон написать с прописной, я (по чисто субъективным причинам!) не возражаю, хотя это своеволие не тянет даже на исключение из правила. А вообще-то говоря, я высказываю своё мнение - и только!